# What is the meaning of "concrete whole"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

When I am reading [Philosophy and Simulation](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=TmbOBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false), I encountered the phrase:

> "concrete wholes"

But I could not understand what does the phrase refer? Could you give me real world examples of concrete wholes and meaning of it?

> And  even  if  one  does  not  have  a  problem                         with  an  ontological  commitment  to  entities  like  these  it  is  hard  to  see                        how   we   could   specify  mechanisms  of  emergence  for  life   or  mind   in                 general,   as   opposed   to   accounting   for   the  emergent  properties   and            capacities  of  concrete  wholes  like  a  metabolic  circuit  or  an  assembly  of               neurons.
>   The   only   problem   with   focusing   on   concrete   wholes   is   that                           this   would   seem    to   make    philosophers   redundant   since   they   do    not                        play any role  in  the elucidation  of  the  series  of events  that  produce            emergent   effects.

Comment: This looks like "Intelligent Design" waffle about ["irreducible complexity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_complexity) to me. That's a pseudoscientific argument maintaining that evolution can't be true because a metabolic circuit or an assembly of neurons is too complicated to arise all at once, but an *incomplete* early version would have no survival advantage (because it wouldn't work at all), so evolution couldn't lead to improvements. Essentially, ***concrete wholes*** are *complex integral structures (which the author thinks only God could have created)*.

Comment: I think this *concrete* is the opposite of *abstract*, i.e., a *concrete whole* is something that emerges from the sum of its parts. To be sure, I'd need to read more, so I'll leave this as a comment. In any case, you can still understand the gist of the sentence, I believe, by skipping this *concrete*.

Comment: @Damkerng: In context, you need to be careful about using ***emerges*** there, since ***emergent complexity*** refers to the (abstract?) *qualities / behaviours / capabilities* of an "irreducibly complex" biological component, rather than the physical "object, body part" instantiating that complexity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Brilliant comments, as usual. I wish you would post your first comment above as an answer, which would successfully put this question to bed before it starts a discussion or invites humor (e.g., "concrete wholes" are dense neutron stars filled with gravel and cement from which no light can escape, etc.).

Comment: @Mark: It *looks like* waffle to me, but firstly, *some* Intelligent Design proponents are very good at using language, and secondly, "concrete whole" could be philosophically useful terminology that doesn't necessarily imply something irreducibly complex as shoehorned into the specious ID argument. If there was a link to the full source I might be able to get a clearer idea of exactly what the author is getting at here, but for the most part I think it should suffice simply to know that two typical examples are *a metabolic circuit or an assembly of neurons* (they're concrete = really exist).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Is this [link](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=TmbOBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false) enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OP's context, ***concrete*** effectively means ***actual, real-world***, as opposed to hypothetical. One particularly common usage is the example in this *dictionary.reverso.net* definition...

> [**concrete**](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/concrete%20example) - relating to a particular instance or object; specific as opposed to general
>    ***a concrete example***

The text specifically identifies *metabolic circuit* and *assembly of neurons* as typical "concrete wholes", meaning that these are actual real-world structures we can observe, that are "complete, irreducible".

In context, the writer seems to be saying such things are problematic for philosophers, because they seem to "spring into existence" in their entirety. Thus they're difficult to explain, since "half a metabolic circuit" wouldn't function at all (so evolution couldn't incrementally improve it, since it would have no reason to exist in the first place, but that's just a specious "Intelligent Design" argument).

Comment: While I can understand how you might arrive at "Intelligent Design" from the excerpt given by the OP, I think if you read on in the link, the author is not making an argument for "Intelligent Design" but possibly the opposite. The author goes on to refute his "the only problem with focussing on..." sentence later in the book. The premise of the book is to defend explaining "emergence" in a non-hierarchal way and the author explicitly refers to "experiments" (simulations).  An argument for "Intelligent Design" would imply hierarchy and the lack of "experiments" for explanation.

Comment: @Peter: It's a lengthy and dense argument, so I must admit I didn't take the trouble to follow it all through. But I did notice he seemed to be distinguishing his own *metabolic circuit, assembly of neurons* examples from typical earlier ones like *Life, Mind, Deity*, and since "half a mind" is obviously better than "no mind at all" (and can thus be an evolutionary stepping stone), I just supposed that was where he was heading. Whatever - my last paragraph above is really just irrelevant opinionating. The basic "meaning" of ***concrete*** as asked about is covered by the preceding text.

Answer (score 0):

**Concrete whole** is a concept used in Aristotle's ***Metaphysics B** to talk about the combination of "matter" (substance) and "shape" (form) to create a **concrete whole**

> "By the matter I mean, for instance, the bronze, by the shape the pattern of its form, and by the compound of these the statue, the **concrete whole**" - Aristotle's [*Metaphysics B*](http://classics.mit.edu/Aristotle/metaphysics.7.vii.html)

The "concrete" (real world, substance/matter) is only part of a **concrete whole**.

So what the author is giving the perspective of thinking about these pathways or structures as an **entirety** of form, function and abstraction.  He makes the observation that science is usually left to explain function and philosophy to explain abstraction.